# git for Windows: remove trailing whitespace when committing

Tags: git, githooks, trailing-whitespace

I've written a `pre-commit` hook to remove trailing whitespace with git for Windows 2.27.0.windows.1.  It seems like a well researched subject, but unfortunately, I cannot get it to work as it should.  This is my `.git\hooks\pre-commit` file:

```
#!/bin/sh
if git rev-parse --verify HEAD >/dev/null 2>&1
then
    against=HEAD
else
    # Initial commit: diff against an empty tree object
    against=$(git hash-object -t tree /dev/null)
fi

git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACM -z $against | xargs -0 | while read LINE
do 
    if [ -n "$LINE" ]; then
        remove_whitespace "$LINE"
        git add "$LINE"
    fi
done
```

Assume I have a file `test.txt` already committed and it has no trailing whitespace.  Now I add trailing whitespace somewhere to it and I want the `pre-commit` to remove that whitespace and not commit anything (since there were no changes).  But this is what happens:

```
C:\> git status
On branch test
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/test' by 17 commits.
(use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   test.txt

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

C:\> git commit test.txt -m test
test.txt
[test 30cb9c0] test

C:\> git status
On branch test
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/test' by 18 commits.
(use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Changes to be committed:
(use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        modified:   test.txt

Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   test.txt

C:\> git add test.txt

C:\> git status
On branch test
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/test' by 18 commits.
(use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

It really did remove trailing whitespace from `test.txt`, since when I `add` the cleaned up file with `git add test.txt` it shows no more changes.  But the `pre-commit` hook seems to cause a file **with** trailing whitespace to be in the staged area and a file **without** trailing whitespace not yet staged for commit.

How can I process all files that are about to be committed, commit output of said processing, but only if that caused a change to the already committed version?

Comment: Why `git diff -z | xargs -0 | while read LINE`? Why not just `git diff | while read LINE`?

Comment: Otherwise filenames with spaces will cause trouble.

Comment: Perhaps add `-n 1` to the `xargs` arguments, to make sure it processes only one file at a time, as I'm pretty sure that's what you want. (Also, for clarity, I'd rename `$LINE` to `$FILE`. )